Localness of regularity at a boundary point for the Dirichlet problem
In the book "Harmonic measure" by Garnett and Marshall, when proving a criterion for regularity at a finite boundary point $\zeta \in \partial \Omega$ for the Dirichlet problem, where $\Omega \subset \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is a domain, the authors claim that the definition of regularity is enough to replace $\Omega$ with a subdomain satisfying a certain property:


Here the definition of regularity is as follows: If $\zeta \in \partial \Omega$ where $\Omega \subset \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is a domain, then $\zeta$ is regular for the Dirichlet problem in $\Omega$ if for every continuous function $f \in \mathbb{\overline{\mathbb{C}}}$, the Wiener solution (or the Perron solution, since these coincide) to the Dirichlet problem in $\Omega$ for the boundary values $f \restriction \partial \Omega$, i.e. $u_{f} = \int_{\partial \Omega} f(w) d \omega(z , w , \Omega)$ satisfies:
$$ \lim_{z \rightarrow \zeta ; z \in \Omega} u_f(z) = f(\zeta)$$.
Here $d \omega(. , w , \Omega)$ is the harmonic measure of $\Omega$.
I understand that it is possible to approximate the boundary components of $\Omega$ in each annulus $A_n$ by such $C^2$ Jordan curves so as to get a subdomain $\Omega'$ with the property the authors describe (so that the series (7.2) still diverges), and for which $\zeta$ is still a boundary point of $\Omega'$. What I do not understand is why showing regularity of $\zeta \in \partial \Omega'$ is sufficient to guarantee regularity of $\zeta \in \partial \Omega$.
I think this has something to do with the fact that regularity at a point is a local property, it only depends on the behaviour of $\Omega$ in a neighbourhood of $\zeta$, and somehow these approximating subdomains capture enough of that behaviour (at least we could take finer and finer approximations to capture it) so regularity for all such subdomains is enough to establish regularity of $\Omega$. The issue is I can't see how to make this argument precise using just the definition of regularity.
